# Search Db Code Add-in for Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

After 5 versions of Visual Studio I think I should be able to right mouse click on a Stored Procedure node of a database connection in the Server Explorer window and be able to search (at least) SQL Server code for the occurrence of a string.

I don't want to have to rely on running an Stored Procedure to search SYSCOMMENTS. I want a real a GUI tool that is integrated with Visual Studio.

Does anyone know of one, preferably free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sql search by redgate is free http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_search/index.htm
Integrates with SSMS

Answer (score 0):

I think Redgate's tool mentioned above is your answer. Also, SSMS Tools Pack has a free data search tool that will search Table, View or Database Data .

http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/